# 'Состав' аудио файла

Tags: c#

Заинтересовал такой вопрос, несколько раз случайно открывал редактором аудио файл и ни при одной кодировке не увидел внятного содержимого :( собственно вопрос: что же в нем написано ? И при помощи чего это можно увидеть?

Comment: Блеск! А что Вы там хотели увидеть? Битмапы нот? А насчёт увидеть -- попробуйте хотя бы audacity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Каждый аудио файл, как и видио, это набор байт. Для того, чтобы проигрыватель мог отобразить картинку, или проиграть мелодию такие файлы структурированы. Структура файла зависит от кодека. Для определения кодека и перемещения по фреймам в начале файла находится  служебная информация. Обычно это тип кодека (может быть закодирован несколько раз), размер фрейма, набор аудио дорожек, набор видео дорожек, размер, длинна и другие атрибуты. Каждый формат предусматривает свои поля.

Для более подробной информации вам лучше спрашивать более конкретно и читать специфическую литературу.

Если вы хотите посмотреть, что в файле, напишите простую программку на С или С++, которая будет открывать файл и считывать данные посимвольно (тип `char`, кодировка ASCII). Затем выводите это на экран.

Answer (score 4):

Описание форматов свободно доступно, например: [цифровые аудиоформаты](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B). Если вы откроете файл какого-либо формата в текстовом редакторе (типа блокнота), то вы увидите просто набор случайных символов, поскольку звуковой файл - это бинарный файл по сути. Если вы откроете файл в специальном редакторе звука, то увидите сигнал и его характеристики (частота, моно-стерео и т.п.).

Суть в том, что работать с форматом надо в соответствии со спецификацией формата.

Answer (score -1):

Я чесно поражаюсь

> Заинтиресовал такой вопрос

Вы случаянно не робот?

> открывал редактором аудио файл и ни
> при одной кодировке не увидел внятного
> содержимого

А еще можно PHP код писать в видео формате, он быстрее там обрабатывается 24 страницы в секунду. :)

> что же в нем написано ? И при помощи
> чего это можно увидеть

Любой аудио редактор, кубейс допустим,

Comment: Да вы я погляжу тролль, зачем мне редактор аудио файлов ? я не собираюсь писать музыку.Меня интересует что там написано внутри. не могут же это быть хаотичные символы. В любом случае должна быть какая-то структура.

Comment: Советую не выражаться.

Так аудио файлы имеют разные расширения и форматы, и о чем ты тут пишешь, просто глупость, погугли какой формат данных у каждого аудио формата и станет тебе яснее.